# Can't run new application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

I've installed RoR in my MacOS X using this guide
http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Here my versions:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
$ rails --version
Rails 3.2.3
$ gem --version
1.8.23
```

I was unable to run my app so I've googled and modified Gemfile using this tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Now this is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

When I run the app using

```
rails server
```

I got this:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load': /Users/giacomo/websrc/rubyrails-app/config/initializers/session_store.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (SyntaxError)
...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_rubyrails-app_session'
                              ^
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:588
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:587
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/giacomo/websrc/rubyrails-app/config/environment.rb:5
    from /Users/giacomo/websrc/rubyrails-app/config.ru:4:in `require'
    from /Users/giacomo/websrc/rubyrails-app/config.ru:4
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/giacomo/websrc/rubyrails-app/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/giacomo/websrc/rubyrails-app/config.ru:1
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because the new ruby has another syntax for hash. Tutorial that you used is outdated, I would suggest to try this: http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails.html 
This is the best I could find. And also it is constantly updated.

In your case you need just to install new version of ruby and then reinstall rails.

Comment: Updating to 1.9.3 on Mac OS I'm not able anymore to run `bundle install`, I've installed all deps manually using `gem install ...` and now I can point my browser to `http://localhost:3000/`. Updated guide helped!

Answer (score 4):

By using Ruby 1.9.x instead of 1.8.7.

Or by opening `/Users/giacomo/websrc/rubyrails-app/config/initializers/session_store.rb` and replacing:

```
key: '_rubyrails-app_session'
```

With:

```
:key => '_rubyrails-app_session'
```

And opening `/Users/giacomo/websrc/rubyrails-app/config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb` and replacing:

```
wrap_parameters format: [:json]
```

With:

```
wrap_parameters :format => [:json]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for prompt response. Now I'm sure running 1.9.3. I've recreated the app but now I'm getting segmentation fault when running `bundle install`: `Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/./Users/giacomo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]`.

Comment: Sorry, that's a different problem. I did a quick Google, but I don't think I can help you with that.

Comment: I'm having __little luck__ with Rails, but I'm very interested in. I'm trying also to run it in Ubuntu 11.04 (same version of Rails). But when I create a new app I get this: `... run  bundle install
/home/developer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
... 
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler issue tracker at ...`

Comment: that's kind of weird that those values (which are default, and supposed to run on 1.9.x by default too) have to be changed